# Writing cmd output to a file is not working with Tomcat :(

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, process

I'm using a java process to open cmd to run a command, then save the output to a text file.

```
    ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
    commands.add("cmd.exe");
    commands.add("/c");
    commands.add("cd "+System.getenv("LOGSTASH_PATH")+" && start /B cmd.exe /c  \"logstash --config.test_and_exit -f "+configFileName+"\""+" > testing.txt");              
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    Process subProcess = builder.start();
    Thread.sleep(50000);
    subProcess.destroy();
```

This piece of code works when i try this with eclipse,But when i generate a war out of this and deploy in tomcat, it doesn't work. What could be the problem?

How to solve this?

Comment: What does 'it doesn't work' mean? Do you get any error? Or the output is not as expected by you?

Comment: No errors. It doesn't write to the file

Comment: May be try putting some log statements and try to find out the exact line where it fails

Comment: Not crashing on any of the lines. Just doesn't write to the file

Comment: `&&` is something that the shell uses to connect two processes. You can't use it as part of your command.

Call `directory()` on your `ProcessBuilder` instance instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem may be with the `CD` instruction:

- Check that the `LOGSTASH_PATH` environment variable is available in the Tomcat process.
- In case the current Tomcat directory and the `LOGSTASH_PATH` belong to different drives, add a `/d` qualifier:

  ```
  "cd /d "+System.getenv("LOGSTASH_PATH")+ ...
  ```

(Tough is much better to replace the `cd` call by a Java call to `directory(File)` instead, as @nitind pointed).